# How to convert sentence into array of strings (list) in python without using split or any fancy function

Tags: python

I would like to convert the sentence into array of strings

Input : I am xyz

Output : ["I","am","xyz"]

So, could you please let me know where am I making logical mistake?
Below is the code written in which I am accepting Input_Sentence from user

```
start =0
i=0
return_array = []
for i in (0, len(Input_Sentence)):
   if " " == Input_Sentence[i:i+1]:
       return_array.append(Input_Sentence[start:i+1])
       start = i + 1
   i += 1
return_array.append(Input_Sentence[start:i+1])
return_array.append(Input_Sentence)
```

Comment: What should be considered the "fancy function"? :)

Comment: The logical mistake is not using `str.split()`. If you can explain why that constraint exists, then people might understand better how to answer.

Comment: It is the requirement just to understand how the basic string operations are done. Right now, I am getting output as "I am xyz"  But, I want it as a list without using built in function

Comment: Please don't tag both versions of Python unless absolutely necessary. If you don't care what version the answer is in, just tag the question `[python]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code corrected:

```
Input_Sentence = 'I am xyz'
start = 0
i = 0
return_array = []
for i in range(len(Input_Sentence)):
    if " " == Input_Sentence[i:i + 1]:
        return_array.append(Input_Sentence[start:i + 1])
        start = i + 1
    # i += 1
return_array.append(Input_Sentence[start:i + 1])
# return_array.append(Input_Sentence)
print return_array
```

You needed range function to do the for loop up to length of `Input_Sentence`. Also you don't need to increment `i` every time. It gets incremented automatically. The last `append` of `Input_Sentence` is not needed.

Use a debugger and breakpoints to be able to see what's wrong! :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in function for this:

```
input_= "I am xyz"
output_ = input_.split()
print(output_ )
```

OUTPUT:

> ['I', 'am', 'xyz']